# How can I add multiple void methods to a class in Flutter ? (Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'.)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in Flutter, I'm building a counter app and I wanted to add the functionalities of "On Clear" and "Decrease" not only increase the counter on click. I thought it'd be logical to add another two methods inside the class MyHomePage but it gives me the error of

> Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'.

I work another way around my code but what if I want to call a method inside that class that does that?
Here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "Hello Code Palace",
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple),
        home: MyHomePage(title: "Hello app!"));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

   void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      ++_counter;
    });
   /*void _decreaseCounter() {
      setState(() {
        --_counter;
      });*/
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("The button has been pressed"),
            Text(
              " $_counter times",
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0, bottom: 24.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed:  ()=>setState(()=> --_counter),
            tooltip: "Decrease",
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 265.0, bottom: 24.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: "Increase",
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 130.0, bottom: 24.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: ()=>setState(()=> _counter = 0),
            tooltip: "Increase",
            child: Icon(Icons.clear_all),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

If you see a way to arrange the buttons at the bottom in a more organized way I'd appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add new function outside of `_incrementCounter()`.

Please check the below code :

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

   void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      ++_counter;
    });
  }

   void _decreaseCounter() {
      setState(() {
        --_counter;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it, I set the function where it was supposed to be and still got the same error, I realized that doing the override of everything again worked and get rid of the previous code. The word build on the override wasn't being recognized for some reason. Thank you for answering I'll select your answer as the correct one